# Elastic Search blank `should` returning results

Tags: elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I'm running a `should` query with any empty list against an index. I'm expecting it to return 0 results since there are no `should` queries/filters to match against:

(Syntax is Chewy but pretty close to regular ES)

```
OrganizationsIndex.filter(
   bool: {
     must: [
       {
         bool: {
           should: [],
    minimum_should_match: 1
         }
       }
     ]
   })
```

However, it returns all the documents in the index. Is that expected behavior? Is there a way that I could make `should: []` always return 0 documents?

Comment: Having no constraints in your bool query, it is equivalent to a `match_all`query.

Comment: @Val Thanks. If you put that as an answer I'll accept. Could you point me to some documentation on that so I could understand more about the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour was changed in **1.3.3** version of Elasticsearch. Before, the empty should clause was treated as no match, and afterwards as it was mentioned by @Val it became `match_all` query.

From the discussion on the issue:

> When a query with just a bool {} is run on its own, the empty bool
>   clause in this case does not throw a NPE and is treated as a valid
>   query, except that it returns no documents (when it should really be
>   returning a match_all):

The link to this GitHub issue - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7240